# CentOS 7: 'pecl' command not doing anything after install

Tags: php, centos, pear, imagick, pecl

I'm trying to install Imagick (ImageMagick PHP extension), so I followed instructions, all of them say you need PECL and therefore should install PHP PEAR - `yum install php-pear` - and some other stuff, like `php-devel` and `gcc`, though not all instructions mentions them, so I guess those are optional.

Even so, I installed the bunch, and then issued the command `pecl install imagick`: nothing. There is zero output. When I run `pecl`: nothing. If I look up `/usr/bin/pecl` it's definitely there, but it does not do or output anything, not even a warning.

I've read posts about `pecl` responding with warnings, or CentOS saying it's missing, but mine seems to be present and gives no warnings, so what can I try? Why is PECL not doing anything?

I've tried to restart Apache en even rebooting the system, and fetched the install from another repo (remi), but to no effect...

Comment: are you running php7

Comment: No, it's still 5.4.

Comment: You should prefer package over "build from sources", so, yum install php-pecl-imagick

Comment: @RemiCollet: thanks for the tip, it works now!! Interesting I don't see installing it like this mentioned in any online instruction (and I've read through quite a few). Could you elaborate, why it is better doing it like this (just curious)? I wanted to ask you to post your answer, so I can accept it, but `pecl` still does not do anything. I still can't figure out why, therefore my original question remains 'unanswered'...

Comment: Build from sources... requires tons of "devel" package which are obviously unwanted on production server, and using "binary" package is simpler to support, as everyone use the same extension. BTW, no idea about your initial issue, as I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the answer was in the PHP error log, which was kept at a custom (ie. not default) location, so I had to go look for it.

`open_basedir restriction in effect`

I needed to include `/usr/share/pear` in the `open_basedir` setting in the `php.ini` file. Without it, PHP will throw an error in the background and `pecl` will return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

**Take a look at the PHP error logs**, I found my problems there.

I needed to add these to the open_basedir directive in php.ini:

```
open_basedir = /usr/local/lib/php/:/tmp/:/sbin/:/bin/:/usr/sbin/:/usr/bin/:/root/:/usr/local/etc/
```

I also needed to enable these php functions I had disabled:

> **ini_get, ini_set, php_uname, popen, chmod, pclose, exec**